# Приложения на React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

В документации читал, что React Native - это не webView и не html-технологии. То есть, это не как Elektron-приложения, которые по сути являются встраиваемыми веб-браузерами с веб-страницами.

Можете сказать, компилируются ли приложения на React Native в нативный код. Например, если для платформы Android, то в java-код и дальнейшей компиляцией java-кода в байт-код, и т.д., как вообщем и должно быть (как мне кажется) если смотреть на название технологии?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Можете сказать, компилируются ли приложения на React Native в нативный код.

Нет.

В React-Native код приложения пишется на JS и исполняется на JavaScript-core для iOS/Android и в режиме дебага код исполняется прямо в браузере (V8 если у вас Chromium based browser).

Начиная с недавних пор есть JSI (JavaScript Interface)

https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/91

Который является абстракций и дает возможность использовать любую реализацию, к примеру новый HermesJS engine, но это будет использоваться только для Android (ибо Apple не дает возможность использовать движки кроме JavaScript Core)

Архитектурно мы имеем:

1. JS код исполняется в JS engine (JS thread)
2. Main thread отвечает за отрисовку
3. Все нативные модули запущены в отдельных тредах (условно, зависит от платформы)

Теперь по частям, как работает render (вкратце):

1. JS -> React (JSX) (мы делаем render какого-то компонента)
2. React (JSX) -> React.createElement (JSX трансплитируется в JS код с помощью babel/typescript)
3. React.createElement -> React -> react-native-reconcilier(https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)
4. JS thread общается с нативным UIManager
5. Main thread рисует ваш компонент

Рекомендую глянуть доклад:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Архитектура React Native для JS-разработчика on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4MnR41SHZc)